# Pandas Sort Values By Date Doesn't Sort By Year

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a large data set that is in this format

[image]

I'd like to order this data set by the "created_at" column, so I converted the "created_at" column to type datetime following this guide:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-sort-a-pandas-dataframe-by-date/

```
data = pd.read_csv(PATH_TO_CSV)

data['created_at'] = data['created_at'].str.split("+").str[0]
data['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(data['created_at'],format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")

data.sort_values(by='created_at')
```

But it's not sorting by year as expected. The values starting with 2012 should be at the top, but they aren't

```
print(data)
print(type(data['created_at'][0]))
```

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: sort_values doesn't sort inplace. you need to assign it back to the df like `data = data.sort_values(by='created_at')`

Comment: Got itttttt. Yup that worked! Wanna make an answer? I'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comments already stated. the sorted df needs to be assigned again. `sort_values` doesn't work inplace by default.

```py
data = data.sort_values(by='created_at')

# OR 

data.sort_values(by='created_at', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

With a datetime type, this should be able to sort directly, make sure to assign the output as sorting is not in place:

```
# no need for an intermediate column nor to pass the full format
data['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(data['created_at'].str.split("+").str[0])

# assign output
data = data.sort_values(by='created_at')
```